# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Catalog_Type_Simple::getSelectionsCollection()

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting above fatal error, while trying to execute following action

```
public function singleattributeAction()
{
    $configurableId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $optionId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('option_id');
    $attributeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
    $bundleId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('bundle_id');
    $attributes = Zend_Json::decode($this->getRequest()->getPost('attributes'));

    $currentAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);

    $bundleOption = Mage::getModel('bundle/option')->load($optionId);
    $configurableProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($configurableId);

    $col = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()
        ->getUsedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        //->addFilterByRequiredOptions(); show custom options

    //Get all product ids related to bundle product
    $bundle = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($bundleId);
    $selectionCollection = $bundle->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
        $bundle->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundle), $bundle
    );
    foreach($selectionCollection as $selection)
    {
        $productIds[] = $selection->getProductId();
    }

    // Filter for set attributes
    $returnEmpty = false;
    foreach($attributes as $attributeKey => $attributeValues)
    {
        if(is_numeric(current($attributeValues))) {
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeKey);
            $col->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getName(), array('in', $attributeValues))->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in', $productIds));
        } else {
            $returnEmpty = (count($attributes) == 1) ? true : false;
        }
    }
    // ASHOT add $filteredSortedValues and $sortedOptions.
    $filteredValues = array();
    $sortedOptions = array();
    $filteredSortedValues = array();

    if($returnEmpty == false) {
        foreach($col as $simple_product){
            $frontendValue = $simple_product->getResource()->getAttribute($currentAttribute->getName())->getFrontend()->getValue($simple_product);
            $sortedOptions = $simple_product->getResource()->getAttribute($currentAttribute->getName())->getSource()->getAllOptions('positions');
            // Do not add disabled products
            if($simple_product->getStatus() != 2) {
                $filteredValues[] = array(
                    'value_index'   => $simple_product->getData($currentAttribute->getName()),
                    'store_label'   => $frontendValue
                );
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($currentAttribute) && count($currentAttribute) > 0) {

        foreach ($sortedOptions as $sortedOption){

            $temp = array('value_index' => $sortedOption['value'], 'store_label' => $sortedOption['label']);
            if (in_array($temp, $filteredValues)) {
                $filteredSortedValues[] = array(
                    'value_index'   => $sortedOption['value'],
                    'store_label'   => $sortedOption['label']
                );
            }
        }

        $productAttribute = array(
            'product_id' => $configurableId,
            'attribute_id'  => $currentAttribute->getAttributeId(),
            'label'     => $currentAttribute->getFrontendLabel(),
            'values'    => $filteredSortedValues
        );

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template');
        $block->setTemplate('configurablebundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/partials/' . $bundleOption->getType() .'.phtml');
        $block->setData(array(
                'option_id'         => $optionId,
                'attribute'         => $productAttribute,
                'attribute_order'   => 0,
                'filteredValues'    => $filteredSortedValues
            )
        );

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->renderView());
    } else {
        // No new options to return
        $this->getResponse()->setBody('');
    }
}
```

It is showing getSelectionsCollection() function as undefined. In this module this function is inside

/Wizkunde/ConfigurableBundle/Model/Bundle/Product/Type.php file. I am not sure why it is looking for this function in 
Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Catalog_Type_Simple, according to error.

I have tried placing this function in simple.php file, but still it gives the same error. This is the module's config.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <configurablebundle>
            <class>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model</class>
        </configurablebundle>
        <bundle_mysql4>
            <rewrite>
                <option_collection>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Bundle_Mysql4_Option_Collection</option_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle_mysql4>
        <cataloginventory>
            <rewrite>
                <stock_status>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_CatalogInventory_Stock_Status</stock_status>
            </rewrite>
        </cataloginventory>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <layer>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Catalog_Layer</layer>
            </rewrite>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_configurable>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Catalog_Type_Configurable</product_type_configurable>
            </rewrite>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type_simple>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Catalog_Type_Simple</product_type_simple>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
        <catalogsearch>
            <rewrite>
                <layer>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer</layer>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Bundle_Product_Type</product_type>
                <product_price>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Bundle_Product_Price</product_price>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Model_Checkout_Cart</cart>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <configurablebundle>
            <class>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block</class>
        </configurablebundle>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>         
                <adminhtml_sales_order_view_items_renderer>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Bundle_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Items_Renderer</adminhtml_sales_order_view_items_renderer>
                <sales_order_items_renderer>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer</sales_order_items_renderer>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle</catalog_product_view_type_bundle>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Checkbox</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Multi</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>
                <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option_search_grid>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Block_Bundle_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option_Search_Grid</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option_search_grid>                    
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>            
    </blocks>
    <helpers>            
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>    
                <catalog_product_configuration>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle_Helper_Catalog_Product_Configuration</catalog_product_configuration>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>            
    </helpers>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <bundle>
                    <allowed_selection_types>
                        <configurable />
                    </allowed_selection_types>
                </bundle>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <configurablebundle>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Wizkunde_ConfigurableBundle</module>
                <frontName>wizbundle</frontName>
            </args>
        </configurablebundle>
    </routers>
    <layout>
         <updates>
              <configurablebundle>
                    <file>configurablebundle.xml</file>
              </configurablebundle>
         </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <configurablebundle>
                                        <title>Configurable Bundle</title>
                                        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                    </configurablebundle>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

I searched related to this issue, found a lot of threads but none worked in my case.
Interesting thing is that this problem I have on live site. This module is working fine on staging and not showing any errors. I have compared each and every folder of this extension on staging and live, it is same.

Can anyone have a look and let me know what could be the error.

Have a look at the screenshots:
https://prnt.sc/j69osf
[image]

Comment: If you guys want anymore details related to the problem then please let me know

Comment: Are you sure that "bundle_id" from the request parameters is the id of a bundle and not of a simple?

Comment: @Fra H I have added images related to your question. Please check.